# Auto insert same data in many tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I am developing an application where multiple companies can create their account and use it as their own. And each company can create multiple users for their own company. Each company can access their own data not other. So, I have a `company_id` column in every table, many table has `user_id` column too. In order to insert the `company_id` and `user_id` I have to provide them manually in every store methods like this:

```
$request['company_id'] = Auth::user()->company_id;
$request['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
Land::create($request->all());
```

I have to mention both columns in model too.

```
$fillable = ['company_id','user_id','other_column','more_column'];
```

I want to auto insert the value of current company id and current user id in database, whenever any data inserted in table.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to develop a set of classes that models the company and user currently connected to your application. Then you can encapsulate the current company id and user id in the class code, and also encapsulate database operations in the same class. That way those id's will always be available as class variables.

Another creative solution would be to set MySQL [user-defined session variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) as you open a connection to the database. You can develop triggers on the tables to populate the company id and user id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER defaults_on_insert BEFORE INSERT ON SomeTable
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.company_id = @company_id, NEW.user_id = @user_id;
```

This seems quite a bit risky though. If the database connection drops and has to be reconnected, your code has to reestablish the session variables. It's also kind of incompatible with the typical client-side object that represents the database object, because there's not a clear way for the client-side object to be notified about values the trigger fills in.

The bottom line is that you're probably better off just making sure company id and user id are supplied when you create new rows.